# Почему появляется ошибка undefined?

Tags: javascript

Почему выводит `undefined`?

```
function rush (filename){
    (function(){
        var res = filename.split(".");
        var b = res[res.lenght - 1];
        return b;
    })();
}
alert(rush("work.tt"));
```

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Можно узнать зачем внутри функции код обёрнут в самовызывающуюся функцию?

Comment: я думал может проблема в замыкании, не пойму почему теряет результат

Comment: @lesha310392, при таких ошибках хорошо помогает пошаговая отладка.

Comment: Возможно, стоит отметить ответ как верный (галка слева, рядом с голосами).

Answer (score 29):

> *Почему выводит undefined?*

Потому что функция **rush** - ничего не возвращает.

Если убрать все лишнее функцию можно записать так:

```
function rush (filename){
    (function(){...})();
}
```

Отсюда хорошо видно отсутствие *return*. Поэтому результат этой функции *всегда* - *undefined*.

Решение *"в лоб"* - добавление *return*

```js
function rush(filename) {
  return (function() {
    var res = filename.split(".");
    var b = res[res.lenght - 1];
    return b;
  })();
}
console.log(rush("work.tt"));
```

При добавлении можно заметить, что все равно не работает. Так как допущена опечатка

```
lenght -> length
```

```js
function rush(filename) {
  return (function() {
    var res = filename.split(".");
    var b = res[res.length - 1];
    return b;
  })();
}
console.log(rush("work.tt"));
```

Теперь видно, что самовызывающаяся функция не нужна

```js
function rush(filename) {
  var res = filename.split(".");
  var b = res[res.length - 1];
  return b;
}
console.log(rush("work.tt"));
```

Также, для получения последнего элемента массива можно использовать [функцию *pop*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```js
function rush(filename) {
  return filename.split(".").pop();
}
console.log(rush("work.tt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function rush (filename){
    var res = filename.split(".");
    return res[res.length - 1];
}
alert(rush("work.tt"));
```