# undefined при попытке распарсить json

Tags: jquery, json

Собственно, пытаюсь запарсить объект и получаю undefined.

```js
function iataToCity(iata) {
    return $.getJSON('http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/cities.json')
 .then(function(cities){
  if(cities) {
   for (var city in cities) {
    if (cities[city].code && cities[city].code == iata) {
     return cities[city].name_translations.ru;
    }
   }
  } else {
   console.log('Error occured while trying to parse cities.json');
  }
 });
};

$(function(){
  $('body').append('<div>'+ iataToCity('IEV') + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

В чём проблема? Обычно распарсить json таким образом получается.

Comment: К слову iata - это что такое?)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму аргумент функции. Разве нет?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, это претензия к стилю именования прост. Почему не работает - написал Grundy, читайте пост по ссылке и думайте.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, судя по всему это _The International Air Transport Association (IATA)_. А значение параметра: [Коды ИАТА](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%98%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%90)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, там в принципе могут быть авиакомпании, самолеты, но в данном случае скорее всего страны

Comment: @Grundy города(регионы), если быть точнее. Прочёл ответ по ссылке, но всё равно не понимаю, в чём проблема.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, смотрите, Вы вставляете в dom результат выполнения функции. У вашей функции результата - нету (то есть нет return, не возвращает она ничего). Это первая проблема. Просто так написать return Вы не можете, так как функция асинхронна (результат будет не сразу. Нет, подождать его нельзя). Для того понять что делать и нужна ссылка приведенная Grundy

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, [данный ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559412/186999) может помочь понять почему undefined

Comment: @Grundy правильно ли я понимаю -  мне нужно указать скрипту, чтобы он ждал загрузки json-файла? await?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, нет. В самой первой ссылке описывается что именно надо делать смотри пункты ответа: Способ 1 и Способ 2

Comment: @Grundy вроде сделал всё правильно, но функция возвращает **[object Object]**

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, предлагаешь угадать что именно и как ты делал? :)

Comment: @Grundy обновил код в топике.

Comment: Похоже не дочитал ответ :) Смотри - функция `iataToCity` - возвращает `Promise`, для доступа к тому что он возвращает ты должен использовать `then`. А ты пытаешься напрямую вставить Promise в строчку `$('body').append('<div>'+ iataToCity('IEV') + '</div>');`

Comment: @Grundy ни черта не понимаю. Я должен использовать then в теле iataToCity, или там, где мне нужно получить от неё результат?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50835/discussion-between-grundy-and-jamesjgoodwin).