# Неясна причина появления ошибки TypeError: Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Перечитал много раз ответы на вопрос [Почему появляется ошибка undefined?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559403/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-undefined)

Но так и не нашел для себя отгадку

Я только изучаю язык, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Есть тест:

```
describe('Wait Test', () => {
  it('should wait for true "false"', () => {
    const wait = new Wait()
    return wait.forTrue(() => false, 5, 1000, 0).then((result) => assert.isFalse(result))
  })
```

В нем вызываются методы и функции класса Wait:

```
const logger = require('./log.util')

const doWait = (action, interval, expectedValue) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (action() === expectedValue) {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), interval)
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => reject(() => {
        return action()
      }), interval)
    }
  })
}

const retrier = async (action, maxCount, interval, count, forFunction, expectedValue) => {
  count++
  logger.info(`[${count}] Wait for true`)
  return doWait(action, interval, expectedValue).then(() => {
    logger.info('Was able to reach expected condition!')
    return true
  }, () => {
    if (maxCount <= count) {
      logger.warning('Was not able to reach expected condition!')
      logger.warning(`[${text}] -> last data from action(): ` + action())
      return false
    } else {
      return forFunction(action, maxCount, interval, count)
    }
  })
}

class Wait {
  forTrue (action, maxCount, interval, count = 0) {
    return retrier(action, maxCount, interval, count, this.forTrue, true)
 };
}
```

И получается в итоге (в строке return retrier(action, maxCount, interval, count, this.forTrue, true)) такая ошибка

```
  1) Wait Test
       should wait for true "false":
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'forTrue' of undefined
      at forTrue (utils/wait.util.js:34:60)
      at doWait.then (utils/wait.util.js:27:14)
```

Не могли бы подсказать, что не так и объяснить поему надо именно так

спасибо

Comment: Так делать не следует. Помимо непосредственной помощи Вам, этот ресурс имеет целью помочь бессчетным поколениям программистов будущего :). Удаление текста вопроса, после того как Вам ответили, идет этому наперекор. PS НЕ забудьте отметить галочкой (слева от ответа) наиболее полезный/правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Wait {
  forTrue (
```

у вас сделаны, как класс и метод. В метод автоматически не передается контекст this. Надо сделать либо:

```
class Wait {
  constructor() {
      this.forTrue = this.forTrue.bind(this);
  }

  forTrue (....) {
      ....
  }
}
```

либо сделать метод стрелочной функцией:

```
class Wait {
  forTrue = (....) => {
      ....
  };
}
```

Comment: Стрелочную функцию использовал: class Wait {
  forTrue = (action, maxCount, interval, count = 0) => {
    return retrier(action, maxCount, interval, count, this.forTrue, true), но в итоге ошибка   forTrue = (action, maxCount, interval, count = 0) => {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: скорей всего - это следствие "недонастройки" babel. Для свойств в классе к бабелу должен быть подключен плагин `@babel/proposal-class-properties`

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь - буду изучать

Answer (score 0):

```
class Wait {
  forTrue (action, maxCount, interval, count = 0) {
    return retrier(action, maxCount, interval, count, this.forTrue.bind(this), true)
 };
}
```